# Using map or reduce or filter, in Scheme, count how many elements in the list

Tags: scheme, racket

(number-length '(1 1 0 1 0 0)) this suppose to return 6. I know how to use length and find it but I don't know how do it without length and using map or filter or reduce. Can anybody give some idea?

Comment: What code have you written and tried using any of those options? You can certainly implement `length` using `reduce` alone, or using `map` and `reduce`, or using `map` and `apply`.

Comment: `map` produces a list, preserving structure but not elements. `filter` produces a list, preserving elements but not structure. `reduce` produces a value of your own choosing. Think about which option you need.

Answer (score 1):

**Map and apply:**

```
(define (number-length1 lst)
  (apply + (map (lambda (n) 1) lst)))
```

**Foldl/ reduce:**

```
(define (number-length2 lst)
  (foldl (lambda (list-element n) (+ n 1))
         0
         lst))
```

**Map and foldl/ reduce:**

```
(define (number-length3 lst)
  (foldl + 0 (map (lambda (n) 1) lst)))
```

Comment: Since this seems like homework, and OP mentions `reduce` instead of `foldl`, I wonder if OP is meant to use a version of `reduce` defined in their coursework. You need to be careful about the order of arguments to `fold`-like procedures. Racket `foldl` works as you have shown it, as would Guile Scheme `fold-left`, and SRFI-1 `fold` and `reduce`. But R6RS Scheme `fold-left` has the order of arguments reversed (the accumulator comes first), as does `fold-left` in MIT Scheme (recently deprecated; `fold` there behaves as in SRFI-1). The point is, we don't know what convention OP `reduce` uses.

Comment: @adabsurdum which is also *good*, since it leaves *the OP* to make those adjustments instead of just copy-pasting the code. :)

Comment: @WillNess -- quite so; I was just hoping that the answer might acknowledge that there are differences among fold-like procedures ;)